# Accessing elements of std::vector<std::map<int, unsigned char>>grid gives error "Expression must have a class type"

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++17, member-access

I've searched far and wide and can't find an answer. Why can't I access the elements? It gives me the error: "Expression must have a class type". I have no idea what this means. Can someone give me a solution to this please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::map<int, unsigned char>>grid =
    {
        {std::make_pair(1,'-'), std::make_pair(2,'-'), std::make_pair(3,'-') },
        {std::make_pair(4,'-'), std::make_pair(5,'-'), std::make_pair(6,'-') },
        {std::make_pair(7,'-'), std::make_pair(8,'-'), std::make_pair(9,'-') }
    };
//This doesn't work
    std::cout << grid.at(0).at(0).second
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
 std::cout << grid.at(0).at(1);
```

instead of

```
std::cout << grid.at(0).at(0).second;
```

It is the same as

```
std::cout << grid.at( 0 ).begin()->second;
```

provided that the element with the key `1` is the first element in the selected map.

That is in the second call of the member function `at` you have to specify a key in the map. In this case the function will return the corresponding value that in your case has the scalar type `unsigned char`.

The member function `at` is declared like

```
T& at(const key_type& x);
const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
```

For a given key it returns the corresponding value.

Within the map at index `0` in the vector initialized like

```
{std::make_pair(1,'-'), std::make_pair(2,'-'), std::make_pair(3,'-')
```

keys are `1`, `2`, and `3`.

So you may use expressions

```
grid.at(0).at(1)
grid.at(0).at(2)
grid.at(0).at(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`grid.at(0)` will give you a `std::map<int, unsigned char>`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), calling `.at(key)` on a map will give you the value corresponding to that key.

So if you'd done:

```
std::cout << grid.at(0).at(1);
```

You'd see '-' from the pair `(1, '-')` in the first map.

If instead you wanted to get the first pair, you should use `.begin()`:

```
std::cout << grid.at(0).begin()->second;
```

See it in action: https://ideone.com/YmLIvK

Comment: I have a std::vector of maps. This doesn't solve my problem of why I am getting this error.

Comment: @GeorgeAustinBradley std::map [at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) 

`Returns a reference to the mapped value of the element with key equivalent to key. If no such element exists, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.`

Comment: No, this solves your problem. Can you try reading the answer again.

Comment: Just trying to work it out a second to get my head round it.